# NetLogo: How to change shape of a turtle if condition is true?

Tags: if-statement, conditional-statements, netlogo, agent-based-modeling

I want to make 2 turtles(a male and a female) get married. I have 2 different shapes for males and females in my simulation.

If a female meets a male on the same patch, they get married. When they do, I want to bundle them as one unit (i.e. I want to delete one of the turtles, and change the other to a third shape indicating a married couple).

How can I do this. I am already lost at the "meeting" stage.

What I have:

```
if any? other turtle-here with [?????]
```

**Pseudocode:**
if female on_same_patch_as_male:

change her marital-status to married

Remove [one of the two turtles]

change the shape of the remaining turtle to "married-couple-icon"

Any help is appreciated

Comment: I imagine you are using breeds?

Comment: `set shape "..."` should do the trick

Comment: But as Matteo said, I prefer breeds over just using different shapes when working with multiple types of turtles.

Comment: @Matteo No, I am not using breeds. Do you think I should use different breeds for males and females?

Comment: @LeirsW I tried, but it isn't doing what it is intended, especially that I need to kill one of the turtles before changing its shape.

Comment: @Am95 Well, you could for example always ask a female to change the shape to married, and then ask any male who has a "married" on their patch to die.